# Make windows 7 partition active

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

Looks I have removed active partition flag from my HDD with windows 7. Disc is not booting anymore. What is the easiest  way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [**method two**](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/71432-partition-mark-active.html):

- Boot from repair disc / Boot-USB
- Enter **diskpart**, then **list disk** after diskpart is loaded.
- Enter select disk [number of the disk the partition is on], e.g. **select disk 0**.
- Enter **list partition**, followed by select partition [partition number], e.g. **select partition 1**.
- Type **active**: there you go! You can now close the command prompt and reboot your computer.

[image]

And [here](http://thpc.info/how/make_active.html) you can learn how to make a partition active by using Linux Live CD.

Comment: Ok, I have done that, but now I have message 'BOOTMGR is missing'. I have looked at the disc content from console - file system is ok - I can see files and dirs.

Comment: Check the boot sequence in BIOS and make sure the correct hard drive or other bootable device is listed first

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Windows disk is in the DVD drive, then perform the following...

Open up command prompt and select your DVD drive (replace D: with your DVD drives letter)

D:
cd boot

Now type this:

bootsect /nt60 SYS /mbr

That should fix it :)